# Service Data not displaying in Component Angular4

Tags: angular

I want to return the data from service to component but when i user the service variable to return the data no error appear but just undefined....
kindly guide me through what is just wrong. When using ionic same logic i applied in angular i get the data but not here in angular 4 application.

## signal.service.ts

when i do `console.log(this.signal)`

give me an object array correctly.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule, Http} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()

export class SignalsService {
signal : Array<any>;

constructor(public _http:Http) {
    this._http.get('http://localhost/4x/data.php')
        .subscribe(res =>{

            this.signal =  res.json().data;
            return this.signal
        });

} 
}
```

My component here when i do console.log the signal returning data from service it says **Undefined**

## home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule, Http} from '@angular/http';

import {SignalsService} from '../signals.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    sig :Array<any>;
   constructor(public _http:Http,public _signa:SignalsService) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this._signa.signal);


}
```

### Moreover

when i directly insert the service request of HTTP in home.component.ts in ngOnInit section it works and returning the data but why my service is not working.

Comment: You get the data asynchronously, which means it takes a while. Your component reads the data, before they were received. Use an observable to notify the component about arrival of the data.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you please tell me the reason also any tutorial to solve this problem and understand for future problem.

Comment: Perhaps https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Answer (score 0):

You service implementation is correct but whay do you want to load everything up top in a constructor better have a separate method and call the get on that method , as of now just replace the code in your component to this.

More on [**services**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    sig: Array<any>;
    constructor(public _http: Http) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this._http.get('http://localhost/4x/data.php')
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.signal = res.json().data;
                console.log(this.signal)
            });
    }
}
```

The best solution will be 
**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()

export class SignalsService {

    constructor(public _http: Http) { }

    get() {
        return this._http.get('http://localhost/4x/data.php')
            .map(res => res.json().data);
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';

import { SignalsService } from '../signals.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public _http: Http, public _signa: SignalsService) {

    }
    ngOnInit() { this._signa.get().subscribe(res => { console.log(res) }) }
```

Comment: Why i had to do that ? in many of youtube tutorials they didn't even talk about this .... please tell me the reason ..

Comment: @AHP does it work for you , i am not quite sure why the tutorials said you , but this is the ideal way we handle services

Comment: how are you accessing it ? i guess when you do it in the component isnide ngOninint it displays in log but not in the next line immedately , this is because we are dealing with async code . just use `{{youe var | async}}` in template

Comment: so you are telling `this._signa.get().subscribe(res => { console.log(res) })` this console log returns undefined

Comment: Yes the `this._signa.get().subscribe(res => { console.log(res) })` giving me undefined in console.log

Comment: can you try and check the service and log it there this emans the service is not returning data

Comment: @AHP then it is not possible can you try adding a error block to subscribe

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. What i did was add the subscribe in the ngOnInit just like @Rahul Singh above and i use map on the in the get(). Like this:

**Component**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
sig;
constructor(private _signa: SignalsService) {

}
get(){
 return this._signa.get().map(data => {this.sig = data})
}
ngOnInit() { this.get().subscribe(res => { console.log(res) }) }
```